# gradient of Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I need help to check my code if my way to generate the gradient of a function that contains Legendre polynomials is correct or not.

if f is a function in θ and κ ,I need the gradient of f with respect to θ, where its derivative with respect to κ is zero because κ is a constant.The last equation to obtain gradient f is correct or there is another way?

Thanks in advance.

```
k = 0.70945`;
tl0 = -0.021720662277045163` - 0.007146744456323989` I;
tl1 = 0.00019355365528147435` + 6.204118924315627`*^-6 I;
tl2 = 0.0031603066656386166` + 0.0003213571906147552` I;
tl3 = 0.00019355365528147435` + 6.204118924315627`*^-6 I;
t = {tl0, tl1, tl2, tl3}
t // MatrixForm

kappa = 0.0814776349681311`;
 lmax = 3
θmax = 10;
 θarray = 
  Table[(π i)/θmax, {i, 0, θmax}] // N;


f = Sqrt[2/(k*\[Kappa])]*Sum[(2*l + 1)*t[[l + 1]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]array]], {l, 0, lmax}]

gradf = (1/\[Kappa])*Sqrt[2/(k*\[Kappa])]*Sum[(2*l + 1)*t[[l + 1]]*LegendreP[l, 1, Cos[\[Theta]array]], 
{l, 0, lmax}]
```

Comment: OK, but where the parameter `θ` is  used?

Comment: does your answer mean that my way is correct??I used θ as an array in Cosθ. I used LegendreP[n,m,z], where n=L,m=1,z=Cosθ to express dP[L,z]/dθ

Comment: Please post code in `InputForm`; you may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Now, I posted in InputForm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can directly verify that the derivative $dP_l(\cos(\theta))/d\theta $ and $P_l^1(\cos(\theta))$ coincide in the interval $(0,\pi ) $ using the well-known formula

[image: fig1]

Consequently

```
f = Sqrt[2/(k*\[Kappa])]*Sum[(2*l + 1)*t[[l + 1]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]array]], {l, 0, lmax}]
gradf = Sqrt[2/(k*\[Kappa])]*Sum[(2*l + 1)*t[[l + 1]]*LegendreP[l,1, Cos[\[Theta]array]], {l, 0, lmax}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex!

Comment: @Ghady, you're welcome!